# Как получить правильное московское время python/django

Tags: python, django, datetime

Не понимаю как получить правильное московское время для отображения на странице.
Смотрим поле через штатную админку Джанги:

[image: Время/Дата]

Всё отлично и правильно.

Запрос через shell:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Показывает -3 часа.

Пробовал через pytz:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Говорит типа все данные таймзоны уже определены... Как из БД получить время в правильной зоне?

Comment: Решение проблемы:
from django.utils import timezone

ret_time = timezone.localtime(rec_obj.status_set_at)

Answer (score 4):

Тут некоторая сложность)

Во-первых, укажите в settings.py `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'`.
Во-вторых, если вы используете сервер, настройте на нем также локальное время.
В-третьих, если вы используете БД, которая поддерживает временную локализацию, также выставьте московское время.